# Automapper and inheritance from Collection or List

Tags: c#, list, inheritance, automapper

I'm trying to use AutoMapper (v5.1.1) to map an object which inherits from a List or Collection. The map call does not give me an error but the output is an empty list (of correct type though).

I can get a `List<DestinationObject>` or `Collection<DestinationObject>`, but it does not seem to work when having a custom class which enherits from `List<T>` or `Collection<T>`.

I've tried extending the first map definition to include the base class (`List<T>`) but that gives me a StackOverflowException.

```
cfg.CreateMap(typeof(SourceCollection), typeof(DestinationCollection)).Include(typeof(List<SourceObject>), typeof(List<DestinationObject>));
```

What am I missing here?

```
public class SourceCollection : List<SourceObject> {

}

public class DestinationCollection : List<DestinationObject> {

}

public class SourceObject {

    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class DestinationObject {

  public string Message { get; set; }
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{

    AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap(typeof(SourceCollection), typeof(DestinationCollection)); 
        cfg.CreateMap<List<SourceObject>, List<DestinationObject>>().Include<SourceCollection, DestinationCollection>();
        cfg.CreateMap(typeof(SourceObject), typeof(DestinationObject));
    });

    AutoMapper.Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

    SourceCollection srcCol = new SourceCollection() { new SourceObject() { Message = "1" }, new SourceObject() { Message = "2" } };
    DestinationCollection dstCol = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<SourceCollection, DestinationCollection>(srcCol);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to map sourceobject to destinationobject, AutoMapper will do rest of the magic, More on this can be found on this [link](http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Lists%20and%20Arrays&referringTitle=Home)

```
cfg.CreateMap(typeof(SourceObject), typeof(DestinationObject));
```

Comment: Wow, thanks - never tried only that single line :)

Funny the other lines got AutoMapper confused - I was sure it was needed since I used inheritance and there is a chapter just for that in the AutoMapper documentation.

Thanks!

//Mike