# Automapper with inherited list

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

FYI: it's different from this question 
[Automapper and inheritance from Collection or List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971563/automapper-and-inheritance-from-collection-or-list)

Here is my inherited list:

```
public class MyPagedList<T> : List<T>
{
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }

    public MyPagedList()
    {
    }

    public MyPagedList(List<T> items, int count, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
    {
        TotalCount = count;
        PageSize = pageSize;
        CurrentPage = pageNumber;
        TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);
        AddRange(items);
    }
}
```

Here are my objects

```
public class A
{
    public string Ant { get; set; }
    public string Apple { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public string Ant { get; set; }
    public string Ansi { get; set; }
}
```

Finally I am calling these like this

```
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
            cfg.CreateMap<A, B>()
               .ForMember(m => m.Ansi, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Apple));

        });

        var _mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        var fixture = new Fixture();
        fixture.RepeatCount = 5;
        var product = fixture.Create<List<A>>();
        var Alist = new MyPagedList<A>(product, 5, 1, 1);

        var Blist = _mapper.Map<MyPagedList<A>, MyPagedList<B>>(Alist);
```

The problem here is my `BList.TotalPages` is always 0. Somehow the content of the list is being mapped but not the property of `MyPagedList` like `CurrentPage`, `PageSize` and so forth.How can I map the MyPagedList properties using Automapper?

Comment: Did you have a question? You wrote some code and described one of its invariants as "a problem", but you didn't ask a question that has an answer. What's your question?

Comment: You should define the mapping for your derived list as `cfg.CreateMap<typeof(MyPagedList<>), typeof(MyPagedList<>)>()`. In that case, same name property (by convention) will be mapped automatically and that should set `TotalPages` and other properties.

Comment: @EricLippert I edited. Thanks

Comment: @user1672994 I added the cfg.CreateMap(typeof(MyPagedList<>), typeof(MyPagedList<>)); Now i see the values are copied but the base List is empty. Looks like the list is not being copied. ??

Comment: I think one of the aspects of this mapping you'll have to handle yourself. Either the list part or the POCO part. Of course you can avoid that by not doing both in the same class. You should have a list, not inherit from list.

Comment: I added the attribute as a list rather than inherting. Thanks for ur response

Comment: Why the downvote ??