# Asp.net Core how to use ReflectionIT with ViewModel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to use paging with a ViewModel in Asp.net Core 2.2.

You can see my code below

```
 public class KiemDinhLoginViewModel
{
    public string MaTruong { get; set; }
    public string MatKhau { get; set; }
    public string TenDonVi { get; set; }
    public string Quan { get; set; }
    public string DiaChi { get; set; }
    public int MaCapHe { get; set; }
    public bool? Active { get; set; }
    public string Quyen { get; set; }

    public string TenCapHe { get; set; }
}
```

And in my Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AutoMapper;
using KhaoThiKiemDinh.Models;
using KhaoThiKiemDinh.ViewModels;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using PagedList.Core;
using ReflectionIT.Mvc.Paging;

namespace KhaoThiKiemDinh.Areas.Admin.Controllers
{
    [Area("admin")]
    public class DanhSachDangNhapController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ngoaingusgd_com_Context _context;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        public DanhSachDangNhapController(ngoaingusgd_com_Context context, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _context = context;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int page = 1)
        {
            var KiemDinhLogin = _context.KiemDinhLogin.AsQueryable();
            var result = KiemDinhLogin.Include(p => p.MaCapHeNavigation).OrderBy(p => p.Quan);
            var model = await PagingList.CreateAsync(result, 5, page);
            return View(_mapper.Map<List<KiemDinhLoginViewModel>>(model));
        }
    }
}
```

And below is MappingProfile

```
namespace KhaoThiKiemDinh.Models
{
    public class MappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public MappingProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<KiemDinhLogin, KiemDinhLoginViewModel>().
                ForMember(dest => dest.TenCapHe, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.MaCapHeNavigation.TenCapHe));
        }
    }
}
```

At the end Index.cshtml

```
@model ReflectionIT.Mvc.Paging.PagingList<KhaoThiKiemDinh.ViewModels.KiemDinhLoginViewModel>
@using ReflectionIT.Mvc.Paging
@addTagHelper *, ReflectionIT.Mvc.Paging

    @await this.Component.InvokeAsync("Pager", new { paginglist = this.Model })

   <table>...</table>


    <vc:pager paging-list="@Model"></vc:pager>
```

But i get below error

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[KhaoThiKiemDinh.ViewModels.KiemDinhLoginViewModel]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'ReflectionIT.Mvc.Paging.PagingList`1[KhaoThiKiemDinh.ViewModels.KiemDinhLoginViewModel]'.

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: See my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58980561/automapper-with-inherited-list#comment104231389_58980561).

Comment: It seems that your Index view also needs to accept `@model List<KiemDinhLoginViewModel>` to correspond to the data passed from action.